# Bounded type parameters: cannot access subtype methods when overriding

Tags: java, generics, bounded-types

I'm new to using bounded types in Java, and I'm not sure if the following is a programming error because of a bad use of inheritance or a `javac` bug

---

I need to define two different type of objects: things which have to be managed and managers of that things. That's why I created an abstract class to model the common behavior of those things

```java
public abstract class AbstractThing {
    // Common method implemented
    public void hello() {
        System.out.println("HI, I'm AbstractThing");
    }
}
```

and an interface to define the methods that those things' manager must implement

```java
public interface AbstractManager {
    // Operation that a things' manager must implement
    public <T extends AbstractThing> void greet(T t);
}
```

---

So suppose I create two concrete things classes, one of them just inherits the abstract one:

```java
public class Thing extends AbstractThing {
    // Constructor
    public Thing() {}
}
```

but the other one implements an own method:

```java
public class AnotherThing extends AbstractThing {    
    // Constructor
    public AnotherThing() {}
    
    // Extra method which this class implements
    public void goodbye() {
        System.out.println("BYE, I'm AnotherThing");
    }
}
```

---

But when I define a manager as follows:

```java
public class Manager implements AbstractManager {
    
    // Constructor method
    public Manager() {}

    // Implementation of the interface's method fails
    @Override
    public <AnotherThing extends AbstractThing>
    void greet(AnotherThing t) {
        // I can use this method, which AnotherThing inherits from AbstractThing
        t.hello();
        // But I can't use this one defined by AnotherThing
        t.goodbye();
    }

}
```

I get the error:

```
AnotherManager.java:15: error: cannot find symbol
        t.goodbye();
         ^
  symbol:   method goodbye()
  location: variable t of type AnotherThing
  where AnotherThing is a type-variable:
    AnotherThing extends AbstractThing declared in method <AnotherThing>greet(AnotherThing)
1 error
```

And I don't understand why, because it's recognizing the class as `AnotherThing`, but it's dealing it as `AbstractThing`. I've tried to cast the object as the subclass, but it doesn't work

I've also checked that it only happens when I try to access the subtype methods, because the following manager compile and works perfectly:

```java
public class Manager implements AbstractManager {

    // Constructor method
    public Manager() {}
 
    // Implementation of the method defined into the interface
    @Override
    public <Thing extends AbstractThing>
    void greet(Thing t) {
        t.hello();
    }

    // I can overload the method "greet" without overriding the interface 
    // and it works for AnotherThing
    public void greet(AnotherThing t) {
        t.hello();
        t.goodbye();
    }

}
```

Any idea about what's happening there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's why

[image]

It's not difficult to figure out if you do something like this

```
public class Manager implements AbstractManager {
    
    // Constructor method
    public Manager() {}

    // Implementation of the interface's method fails
    @Override
    public <T extends AbstractThing>
    void greet(T t) {
        // I can use this method, which T inherits from AbstractThing
        t.hello();
        // But I can't use this one because T inherits from AbstractThing which does not know this method
        t.goodbye();
    }

}
```

In other words, the word before the "extends" is not supposed to be a class name, but a generic identifier (a variable name).

In this case, since T (or wharever you call it) is AbstractThing, it does not know what goodbye() is.

Now, why your last example works?

Because you're saying that greet receives a object of type AnotherThing, not a generic type such as T.

Comment: Will the type placed before `extends` be always deal as a generic? I mean, although I use the name of an existing class, the parameter is going to be treated a generic and not as an object of that class, right?

Comment: the idea is that you're going to use <X verb C> where X is a variable and C is a class or interface

Answer (score 0):

`AnotherThing` in `<AnotherThing extends AbstractThing>` has nothing to do with the class `AnotherThing`. It's the name a type parameter, same as if it were called `T`. The reason it acts like `AbstractThing` is because that's all we know it is. Your method doesn't know how it's parameterized; all it knows is that it's getting a subclass of `AbstractThing`. This can be useful for constructs where we need to capture the type, but we don't care what subtype it is, e.g.:

```
<T extends AbstractThing> void copy(List<T> from, List<T> to) {
    for (T t : from) {
        t.hello();
        to.add(t);
    }
}
```

But if you want a specialized subclass of `AbstractManager` to manage `AnotherThing`, the type parameter should be on the class, not the method:

```
public interface AbstractManager<T extends AbstractThing> {
    // Operation that a things' manager must implement
    public void greet(T t);
}

public class AnotherManager implements AbstractManager<AnotherThing> {
    @Override
    public void greet(AnotherThing t) {
        t.hello();
        t.goodbye();
    }
}
```

Comment: I understand that approach, but into the problem I'm trying to solve (the real one) I need to overload the `greet` method implementation with different subclasses of `Thing` into the same manager (something similar to the second implementation of `Manager` which I gave). Is there another solution taking that into consideration?

Comment: I'm not sure generics is the right tool for that. You might want to look at the [visitor pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern#Java_example).

Comment: Thank you for the tip, I didn't know that pattern. As I can see, there are some similarities with my problem, but I think applying it in my case is not a good idea, because I'll need to increase the number of subtypes of the class `AbstractThing`